# Blue screen in androidplot

Tags: android, plot, androidplot

I was try library androidplot to create some plots. I copy code from source but only what I see is blue screen with yellow lines. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?
This is code:

```
package com.example.actionbartest;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

import com.androidplot.series.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.ui.AnchorPosition;
import com.androidplot.ui.DynamicTableModel;
import com.androidplot.ui.SizeLayoutType;
import com.androidplot.ui.SizeMetrics;
import com.androidplot.util.PaintUtils;
import com.androidplot.xy.AxisValueLabelFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.FillDirection;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.RectRegion;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XLayoutStyle;
import com.androidplot.xy.XPositionMetric;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYRegionFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYStepMode;
import com.androidplot.xy.YLayoutStyle;
import com.androidplot.xy.YValueMarker;

public class XYRegionExampleActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int FONT_LABEL_SIZE = 13;
    private XYPlot plot;
    private final Number[] series1Numbers = {1, 4, 9, 9, 5, 2, 12};
    private final Number[] series2Numbers = {5, 2, 3, 2, 17, 9, 1};
    private final Number[] series3Numbers = {8, 9, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2};
    private final Number[] series4Numbers = {2, 1, 1, 11, 6, 5, 7};
    private LineAndPointFormatter lpFormatter1;
    private LineAndPointFormatter lpFormatter2;
    private LineAndPointFormatter lpFormatter3;
    private LineAndPointFormatter lpFormatter4;
    static final float PLOT_TITLE_FONT_SIZE_DP = 15;
    static final float PLOT_DOMAIN_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP = 10;
    static final float PLOT_RANGE_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP = 10;
    static final float PLOT_TICK_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP = 10;
    private XYSeries s1;
    private XYSeries s2;
    private XYSeries s3;
    private XYSeries s4;

    private RectRegion rr1;
    private RectRegion rr2;
    private RectRegion rr3;
    private RectRegion rr4;
    private RectRegion rr5;

    private XYRegionFormatter rf1;
    private XYRegionFormatter rf2;
    private XYRegionFormatter rf3;
    private XYRegionFormatter rf4;
    private XYRegionFormatter rf5;

    private CheckBox s1CheckBox;
    private CheckBox s2CheckBox;
    private CheckBox s3CheckBox;
    private CheckBox s4CheckBox;

    private CheckBox r1CheckBox;
    private CheckBox r2CheckBox;
    private CheckBox r3CheckBox;
    private CheckBox r4CheckBox;
    private CheckBox r5CheckBox;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xyregion_example);
        plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.xyRegionExamplePlot);
        s1CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.s1CheckBox);
        s1CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onS1CheckBoxClicked();
            }
        });

        s2CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.s2CheckBox);
        s2CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onS2CheckBoxClicked();
            }
        });

        s3CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.s3CheckBox);
        s3CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onS3CheckBoxClicked();
            }
        });

        s4CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.s4CheckBox);
        s4CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onS4CheckBoxClicked();
            }
        });

        r1CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.r1CheckBox);
        r1CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onCheckBoxClicked(r1CheckBox, lpFormatter1, rf1, rr1);
            }
        });

        r2CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.r2CheckBox);
        r2CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onCheckBoxClicked(r2CheckBox, lpFormatter1, rf2, rr2);
            }
        });

        r3CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.r3CheckBox);
        r3CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onCheckBoxClicked(r3CheckBox, lpFormatter2, rf3, rr3);
            }
        });

        r4CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.r4CheckBox);
        r4CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onCheckBoxClicked(r4CheckBox, lpFormatter2, rf4, rr4);
            }
        });

        r5CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.r5CheckBox);
        r5CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                onCheckBoxClicked(r5CheckBox, lpFormatter2, rf5, rr5);
            }
        });

        seriesSetup();
        markerSetup();
        axisLabelSetup();
        regionSetup();
        makePlotPretty();
        //plot.disableAllMarkup();
    }

    private void onS1CheckBoxClicked() {
        if(s1CheckBox.isChecked()) {
            plot.addSeries(s1, lpFormatter1);
            r1CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
            r2CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            plot.removeSeries(s1);
            r1CheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            r2CheckBox.setEnabled(false);
        }
        plot.redraw();
    }

    private void onS2CheckBoxClicked() {
        if(s2CheckBox.isChecked()) {
            plot.addSeries(s2, lpFormatter2);
            r3CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
            r4CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
            r5CheckBox.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            plot.removeSeries(s2);
            r3CheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            r4CheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            r5CheckBox.setEnabled(false);
        }
        plot.redraw();
    }

    private void onS3CheckBoxClicked() {
        if(s3CheckBox.isChecked()) {
            plot.addSeries(s3, lpFormatter3);
        } else {
            plot.removeSeries(s3);
        }
        plot.redraw();
    }

    private void onS4CheckBoxClicked() {
        if(s4CheckBox.isChecked()) {
            plot.addSeries(s4, lpFormatter4);
        } else {
            plot.removeSeries(s4);
        }
        plot.redraw();
    }

    /**
     * Processes a check box event
     * @param cb The checkbox event origin
     * @param lpf LineAndPointFormatter with which rr and rf are to be added/removed
     * @param rf The XYRegionFormatter with which rr should be rendered
     * @param rr The RectRegion to add/remove
     */
    private void onCheckBoxClicked(CheckBox cb, LineAndPointFormatter lpf,
                                   XYRegionFormatter rf, RectRegion rr) {
        if(cb.isChecked()) {
            lpf.removeRegion(rr1);
        } else {
            lpf.addRegion(rr, rf);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Cleans up the plot's general layout and color scheme
     */
    private void makePlotPretty() {
        // use a 2x5 grid with room for 10 items:
        plot.getLegendWidget().setTableModel(new DynamicTableModel(2, 5));

        // add a semi-transparent black background to the legend
        // so it's easier to see overlaid on top of our plot:
        Paint bgPaint = new Paint();
        bgPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        bgPaint.setAlpha(140);

        plot.getLegendWidget().setBackgroundPaint(bgPaint);

        // adjust the padding of the legend widget to look a little nicer:
        plot.getLegendWidget().setPadding(10, 1, 1, 1);

        // adjust the legend size so there is enough room
        // to draw the new legend grid:
        plot.getLegendWidget().setSize(
            new SizeMetrics(70, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE, 80, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE));

        // reposition the grid so that it rests above the bottom-left
        // edge of the graph widget:
        plot.position(
                plot.getLegendWidget(),
                20,
                XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_RIGHT,
                35,
                YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM,
                AnchorPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);

        // make our domain and range labels invisible:
        plot.getDomainLabelWidget().setVisible(false);
        plot.getRangeLabelWidget().setVisible(false);

        plot.getGraphWidget().setRangeLabelHorizontalOffset(-1);

        // add enough space to ensure range value labels arent cut off on the left/right:
        plot.getGraphWidget().setRangeLabelWidth(25);

        // add enough space to make sure domain value labels arent cut off on the bottom:
        plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelWidth(15);

        plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelVerticalOffset(-6);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(null);
        plot.getGraphWidget().setBackgroundPaint(null);
        plot.setBorderPaint(null);
        plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        PaintUtils.setFontSizeDp(ctx,
            plot.getDomainLabelWidget().getLabelPaint(), PLOT_DOMAIN_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        PaintUtils.setFontSizeDp(ctx,
            plot.getRangeLabelWidget().getLabelPaint(), PLOT_RANGE_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        PaintUtils.setFontSizeDp(ctx,
            plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLabelPaint(), PLOT_TICK_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        PaintUtils.setFontSizeDp(ctx,
            plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint(), PLOT_TICK_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        PaintUtils.setFontSizeDp(ctx,
            plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLabelPaint(), PLOT_TICK_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        PaintUtils.setFontSizeDp(ctx,
            plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint(), PLOT_TICK_LABEL_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        PaintUtils.setFontSizeDp(ctx,
            plot.getTitleWidget().getLabelPaint(), PLOT_TITLE_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        plot.getGraphWidget().getGridLinePaint().setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{1, 2, 1, 2}, 0));
        plot.getTitleWidget().pack();
    }

    /*private void showS1() {
        plot.addSeries(s1, lpFormatter1);
    }*/

    /*private void showS2() {
        plot.addSeries(s2, lpFormatter2);
    }*/

    /*private void showS3() {
        plot.addSeries(s3, lpFormatter3);
    }*/

    /*private void showS4() {
        plot.addSeries(s4, lpFormatter4);
    }*/

    /**
     * Create 4 XYSeries from the values defined above add add them to the plot.
     * Also add some arbitrary regions.
     */
    private void seriesSetup() {


        // SERIES #1:
        lpFormatter1 = new LineAndPointFormatter(
                Color.rgb(100, 25, 20),
                Color.rgb(4, 100, 88),
                Color.rgb(66, 100, 3));
        lpFormatter1.setFillPaint(null);
        lpFormatter1.setVertexPaint(null);
        lpFormatter1.getLinePaint().setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0);

        s1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "S1");

        plot.addSeries(s1, lpFormatter1);

        // SERIES #2:
        lpFormatter2 = new LineAndPointFormatter(
                Color.rgb(100, 25, 200),
                Color.rgb(114, 100, 88),
                Color.rgb(66, 100, 200));

        lpFormatter2.setFillPaint(null);
        lpFormatter2.setVertexPaint(null);
        lpFormatter2.getLinePaint().setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0);

        s2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "S2");

        plot.addSeries(s2, lpFormatter2);

        // SERIES #3:
        lpFormatter3 = new LineAndPointFormatter(
                Color.rgb(200, 25, 200),
                Color.rgb(200, 100, 88),
                Color.rgb(66, 100, 100));
        lpFormatter3.setFillPaint(null);
        lpFormatter3.setVertexPaint(null);
        lpFormatter3.getLinePaint().setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0);

        s3 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series3Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "S3");

        plot.addSeries(s3, lpFormatter3);

        // SERIES #4:
        lpFormatter4 = new LineAndPointFormatter(
                Color.rgb(220, 25, 20),
                Color.rgb(4, 220, 88),
                Color.rgb(1, 100, 225));
        lpFormatter4.setFillPaint(null);
        lpFormatter4.setVertexPaint(null);
        lpFormatter4.getLinePaint().setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0);
        s4 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series4Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,"S4");
        plot.addSeries(s4, lpFormatter4);

        plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
        plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Add some color coded regions to our axis labels.
     */
    private void axisLabelSetup() {
        plot.getGraphWidget().addRangeAxisValueLabelRegion(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 3, new AxisValueLabelFormatter(Color.RED));
        plot.getGraphWidget().addRangeAxisValueLabelRegion(3, 7, new AxisValueLabelFormatter(Color.BLUE));
    }

    /**
     * Add some markers to our plot.
     */
    private void markerSetup() {

        // the easy way to add a marker (uses default font color and positioning):
        plot.addMarker(new YValueMarker(3, "Marker #1"));

        // the comprehensive way:
        plot.addMarker(new YValueMarker(
                7,                                          // y-val to mark
                "Marker #2",                                // marker label
                new XPositionMetric(                        // object instance to set text positioning on the marker
                        3,                                  // 3 pixel positioning offset
                        XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT    // how/where the positioning offset is applied
                ),
                Color.BLUE,                                 // line paint color
                Color.BLUE                                  // text paint color
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Add some fill regions to our series data
     */
    private void regionSetup() {

        // create a new region:
        rf1 = new XYRegionFormatter(Color.RED);

        // we want to create a vertical region so we set the minX/maxX values to
        // negative and positive infinity repectively:
        rr1 = new RectRegion(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 3, "R1");

        // add the new region to the formatter for this series:
        lpFormatter1.addRegion(rr1, rf1);

        // and another region:
        rf2 = new XYRegionFormatter(Color.BLUE);
        rr2 = new RectRegion(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 3, 7, "R2");
        lpFormatter1.addRegion(rr2, rf2);
        lpFormatter1.setFillDirection(FillDirection.RANGE_ORIGIN);
        plot.setUserRangeOrigin(3);

        // the next three regions are horizontal regions with minY/maxY
        // set to negative and positive infinity respectively.
        rf3 = new XYRegionFormatter(Color.GREEN);
        rf4 = new XYRegionFormatter(Color.YELLOW);
        rf5 = new XYRegionFormatter(Color.argb(130,255,0,0));

        rr3 = new RectRegion(0, 2, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, "R3");
        lpFormatter2.addRegion(rr3, rf3);

        rr4 = new RectRegion(2, 4, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, "R4");
        lpFormatter2.addRegion(rr4, rf4);

        rr5 =new RectRegion(4, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, "R5");
        lpFormatter2.addRegion(rr5, rf5);

        lpFormatter2.setFillDirection(FillDirection.RANGE_ORIGIN);
        plot.setUserRangeOrigin(3);
    }
}
```

and xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
            android:id="@+id/xyRegionExamplePlot"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            title="XYRegion Example"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/s1CheckBox"
                  android:text="S1"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/s2CheckBox"
                  android:text="S2"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/s3CheckBox"
                  android:text="S3"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/s4CheckBox"
                  android:text="S4"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/r1CheckBox"
                  android:text="R1"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/r2CheckBox"
                  android:text="R2"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/r3CheckBox"
                  android:text="R3"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/r4CheckBox"
                  android:text="R4"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/r5CheckBox"
                  android:text="R5"
                  android:checked="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what do you expect to see?  What do you think is wrong in a bit more detail?

Comment: I want to see 4 charts, not only blue screen

Comment: Your layout has one plot in it.  If you want 4 different ones you need 4 independent plots in it.

Comment: yes, this is one plot but has 4 lines charts. I don't know why I can only see blue screen without any chart

Comment: Your colours look to specify no alpha so you probobly can only see the last one drawn if it covers the others that is all you will see.  Try switching the fill off by passing in null for the fill colour.